# Managing multiple repositories via their parent project

Tags: git

I have a bit strange question about Git. I have a scenario but not sure how to search for this.

So we have an application built with Laravel and I have 3 branches; master, feature and develop.

We have our clients and for each client we are duplicating the Git repository. This was fine with small changes on each repository. But then the master repo started to get new features, additions etc. Then I need to go for each client and one by one copy new files, changes some existing ones carefully then test test and test. For now there is one master and 4 child repositories.

I am looking something like a inheritance model for these repositories. Let's say all projects have a `User.php` and in one sub repository I want to add additional methods, I should be able to do this with out losing sync with my master repository.

Maybe these are two different topics but I cannot find the best scenario to handle an issue like this.

Maybe I am lacking some vision here :( Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: `We have our clients and for each client we are duplicating the Git repository` Why? Maybe try to solve this via code by using a e.g. role-based model so client `A` has roles `A`, `B`, and `C` and because of that he has access to feature `D` and `E`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by clarifying the repo setup. I will assume the following configuration:

1. A "shared" repo that has features which are common to all clients. This is hosted on an internal server or a hosting service such as GitHub or Bitbucket.
2. A local copy of this shared repo.
3. Repos for each client which are also hosted on an internal server or a hosting service.
4. A local copy of each client repo. These are cloned from the repos in 3 so that their `origin` is already set to the appropriate central repo for each client.

If this is your setup, then syncying a client with the shared repo is pretty straightforward with `git remote`. First add the "shared" repo as a remote:

```
git remote add shared <URL to the shared repo in #1>
```

Now you can interact with a remote named `shared` in the same way you typically interact with `origin`. For example, you can fetch all its branches:

```
git fetch shared
```

You can also pull any of its branches into your current work:

```
git checkout feature-a
git pull shared master
```

Then resolve merge conflicts as usual.